# Not submitting edit rather than "eating" it when it's too late for an edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, chat

I recently experienced a situation in chat where I was typing out a long edit to a question.

When I submitted the edit, rather than getting a message that says "it's too late to edit" and keeping the edit (so I could resubmit it as its own message), the edited message disappeared and I had to retype it out from memory.

Could it be changed so that rather than "eating" (yes, that's the technical term) the message, it instead rejects the edit so that the edited message is retained?

Comment: Maybe you should learn to be more chatty...

Comment: Write the code out in a text editor window, and then paste it into the chat box when you're done.

Comment: @RobertHarvey definitely.  Just thought this was a reasonable feature request :)